# Python async communication between classes

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, coroutine, gevent

I have implemented a class that connects to a websocket to receive asynchronous messages.

```
class websocketClient(...):
    def on_message(self, msg):  # Gets automatically called
        notifyBrokerAbout(msg)  # How to proceed from here?

class Broker():
    self.websocket = websocketClient(...)
    self.websocket.start()

    def heartbeat(self):
        return self.websocket
```

The heartbeat function starts the websocket and returns it. The websocket class itself has an `on_message()` function that acts as a callback that gets triggered every time that a new message is received.

I do not want to call a function from time to time to `GET` the latest `msg` from the websocket out to the Broker, instead I want to `PUSH` these message out to the Broker as soon as they arrive in the `on_message()`.

```
broker = Broker()
hearbeats = broker.heartbeat()

for beat in heartbeats:
    ...
```

[image]

How can I solve this best in Python? I'm looking for a way to push a new message coming in at the `websocketClient`s `on_message()` to `heartbeat()` such that in the main application I can subscribe to that function and wait for updates.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using the reactor pattern -- asynchronous processing of requests, followed by a synchronous dispatch.

You'll find many good examples by searching for "reactor gevent" and "reactor twisted". There are several variations. I'll avoid recommending a specific variation since the overall choice will depend on other system-level issues not evident in your example code.